# Pydub getting back overlay audiofile

Tags: audio, overlay, pydub

is there any possibility of unmixing a file? I have use overlay to mix 2 audios, but I want to get back the original first audio. Is there something in pydub that I can use?

```
sound1 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("/path/to/file1.mp3")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("/path/to/file2.mp3")
output = sound1.overlay(sound2, position=5000)
output.export("mixed_sounds.mp3", format="mp3")
```

Answer (score 1):

The original audio in the `sound1` variable has not been modified, so you can use it right away if you like.

If you mean recovering just the audio from `sound1` from the exported “mixed_sounds.mp3” file, without acccess to the original data, that is not possible unless you know very specific things (for example if `sound2` is silent and you know when `sound1` starts and ends)

Comment: Thank you!, well I need to put noise in the audiofile then sendend and then take off the noise for it to be play. If you have any information on how to do this, it will be well received.

Comment: @avi1074 why do you want to add noise? is it for security purposes? If so maybe use a lib for encryption?

Comment: it was for security and investigation, but you're right, i'll use a encryption library